# Union of two copies of uniform spanning forest on $\mathbb{Z}^3$ is transient?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, random-graphs

Let $G$ be the (random) graph which is the union of two independent copies of the [uniform spanning forest](https://doi.org/10.1214/aop/1008956321) on $\mathbb{Z}^3$.

**Question**: Is (the simple random walk on) $G$ transient almost surely?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you sure your question is complete? What are you asking to show is transient? Usually that refers to a random walk, right? How is that related to the spanning forests?

Comment: @SamHopkins
 There is a strictly definition that transient random graph. But in this question, the random walk is just the simple random walk.